# Laravel API is prepending npm to the response

Tags: php, json, api, laravel-5

I have a project in `Laravel 5.7.9` with an API. When I try to go to any of my routes I get an error saying

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

This was previously working fine so did some testing and noticed the following:

In my `routes/api.php` file I created the following code

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return 'my-test';
});
```

now when I head to `mysite.sandbox/api/test` I get a response saying `npmtest`

[image: ScreenShot]

similarly, when i try to query the API for a JSON response I get my JSON response wrapped with `npm{}`

```
npm{"data":[{"id":324,"titulo":"...","descripcion":"...",...},{"id":323,...},{"id":320,...}],"meta":{"pagination":{"total":3,"count":3,"per_page":15,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"links":[]}}}
```

I'm not sure when this broke but I do remember doing an `npm install` before the error began.
What could be causing this? And how can I fix this? Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

---

**Update**
Here is another situation where `npm` is showing up where it's not suppose to...

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
npmApplication cache cleared!
```

Comment: `grep -R npm *` I'm betting it's in there somewhere before any PHP start tags.

Comment: I'm agree with aynber... Somewhere you should have that "npm" string echoed...

Comment: but if it was echoed then why is it wrapping the response including the closing brackets? @aynber

Comment: It's not wrapping anything. Your API response is outputting a JSON object. The `npm` bit is being output first. At some point, you thought you were in the terminal, but you were in your text editor, and you accidentally typed `npm` into the start of a file. Run @aynber's command and you'll find it.